# Matplotlib subplot how to duplicate ax from one subplot to another?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

How can I have my third subplot be an overlay of the first two without having to just copy/paste the code? Using Python 3.8.3, matplotlib 3.2.1.

```
x1, y1 = [(2,7,1), (6,2,2)]
x2, y2 = [(8,3,0), (1,4,9)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(15, 10));
ax1, ax2, ax3 = ax
ax1.scatter(x1, y1,  c='red', label='Set1');
ax2.scatter(x2, y2, c='black', label='Set2');
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252213/matplotlib-sharex-not-working-as-expected) of yours.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, updated

Comment: @QuangHoang it's a completely different question. The numbers are the same just to make the question reproducible (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as a for loop with if tests:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x1, y1 = [(2,7,1), (6,2,2)]
x2, y2 = [(8,3,0), (1,4,9)]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(15, 10))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    if i != 1:
        ax.scatter(x1, y1, c='red', label='Set1')
    if i != 0:
        ax.scatter(x2, y2, c='black', label='Set2')
plt.show()
```

PS: Contrary to other programming languages, in Python no semicolon is needed at the end of statements. (Python uses newlines and indentation to know what goes together.) However, when used in Jupyter notebooks, the result of the last line of a block is printed out. Many matplotlib functions return some values that often aren't used (e.g. `scatter` returns a list of the points). To suppress such distracting output, a semicolon can be used in the very last statement of a Jupyter block.

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: isn't there a way to do it without a loop? it seems like there should be a one-liner way to do this?

Comment: Although not really recommended for readability, you could write `if i != 1: ax.scatter(x1, y1,  c='red', label='Set1')` all on the same line.